# Why wont the links to other webpages appear when i visit my GitHub website?

Tags: html, github

I have this GitHub website running off the master branch and here is the link to that website ->  https://jpatrickg.github.io/

It shows two bullet points and I have links going to two seperate web pages and they're all in the same directory but the problem is the links aren't appearing on the main page.
Here's the code (3 files) -> https://github.com/jpatrickg/jpatrickg.github.io

I've tried clearing the web browser cache after reading some other threads and that didn't help.  I've also waited a lot longer than 10 minutes after the last commit and waiting didn't help either.

Why aren't the links to antennatypes and freqband pages not appearing to the right of the bullet points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
    <ul>
       <li><a href="antennatypes.html" title="Antenna Types"</a></li>
       <li><a href="freqband.html" title="Frequency Band"</a></li>
    </ul>
```

to:

```
    <ul>
       <li><a href="antennatypes.html">Antenna Types</a></li>
       <li><a href="freqband.html">Frequency Band</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Plus, notice you had a typo (unwrapped `<a>` tag).